# Posting the latest news item from a website without changing past content

Tags: php, rss, vbulletin

What I'm trying to do is have a user on my vBulletin forum post the latest news story from a website each time it's generated using an RSS poster. Unfortunately the website does not have an RSS feed, so I created one based on the source code of the site. The feed pulls in the title & link to the news post. I also want the description of the news post to show in the vBulletin post, so I created a php script (shown below) to collect the description of the post.

My problem now is that with the RSS poster on vBulletin using the php script, it always updates all of its old posts to have the description from the latest post. This is because it uses the php script in every post - always showing the latest post description.

I can't for the life of me think of a way around this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
<?php 
$fullxml = simplexml_load_file('http://feed43.com/efpatches.xml');
$link = $fullxml->channel->item[0]->link;
$page = file_get_contents($link);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($page); 
$divs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach($divs as $div) {
    if ($div->getAttribute('id') === 'G_g_ArticleViewContainer_viewArticleContent_v_hEditor_forView_strArticleContent_Viewer') {
return nl2br(str_replace("&nbsp;","",htmlentities($div->nodeValue,null,'utf-8')));
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Where do the descriptions get set?  That is the code you need to show.

Comment: They don't really get set anywhere as of right now. The code returns the description and the RSS poster posts it as is. The code snippet is what is currently being used in each post.

Comment: So the descriptions come from the XML document?  In that case, you need to look at fixing the XML document, not the code that parses it.

Comment: The descriptions come from the code I posted. The XML document only pulls in the link and the title. I thought you were asking if I sent the data gathered from this code into a database or something. The description gets returned by the return statement in the code.

Comment: Well you are only returning one single value. NOt an array of values corresponding to each item.

Comment: That's right. Because right now this code is being used to post that one single value to my forum. What I'm wanting to do with it is have this code be run one time when a new post is found on the RSS feed and have it generate static content to be posted by the RSS poster. That's what I'm not sure how to do.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just periodically call the RSS feed, get everything in the format you need it for display, and then cache the resulting object on your server.  Whenever you need to show the RSS data in the forum, just load up the cached object and use it.  You can just cache the whole RSS structure in that manner and not have to worry about just updating the latest story from the RSS.